# address-family ipv6 on Cisco 3560G

Tags: ipv6, bgp, bgp-ipv6

Is anyone aware of an IOS version for the C3560G that supports configuring a neighbor to exchange IPv6 routes? Apparently 12.2(37)SE Advanced IP Services can't do it - as soon as you try to activate the address-family it throws `% BGP context not been initialized properly` (great Engrish there Cisco).

For the record, I *have* enabled dual ipv4 & ipv6, it does OSPFv3 just fine.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would require an 'Advanced Enterprise Services' package.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Feature Navigator](http://www.cisco.com/go/fn), that would be a big'ol negative. 'tho the 3560C appears to support it.

Comment: ACK. This is true, there is NO version of 3560, 3750 which officially supports IPv6 BGP. That being said, it actually does work on later IOS releases, and we do run it on production, but if it stops working due to upgrade or defect, you're on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This only will work with advanced enterprise Cisco IOS images. As mentioned abovr the CFN (cisco feature navigator) will support you to find the needed functionality on a certain software/hardware. CFN does even show if the requested feature is supported by the hardware platform. Not all features that actually will work, are supported by the vendor.